# I have a light/dark theme toggle react component that I'm trying to improve

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dark theme toggle switch for my React component that works well, but I know the code could use some work. First I am checking to see what the users' preferences are for light/dark. Then I am setting in local storage what the user has chosen as a preference and then also checking for that value. I'm still learning and would like some feedback.

My requirements:

1. Needs to check the users' system preference for light/dark
2. Needs to persistently keep users light/dark preference throughout the site
3. Add class dark to the body tag in order to active all the CSS changes

Thanks in advance!

````
import React, { Component } from "react";

class LightDarkToggle extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let bodyClassList = document.body.classList;
    let themeSwitch = document.getElementById('switch-style');

      //Here we are checking the USERS' device settings for dark theme
      if(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
        bodyClassList.add('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = true;
      } 
      else if(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches) {
        bodyClassList.remove('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = false;
      }

      //Persisting USERS' theme preference by checking the local storage we set
      if(window.localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark') {
        bodyClassList.add('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = true;
      } 
      else if(window.localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'light') {
        bodyClassList.remove('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = false;
      }

  }

  handleClick() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');

    if(document.getElementById('switch-style').checked === true){
      window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    } 
    else if (document.getElementById('switch-style').checked === false){
      window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="toggle-mode">
        <div className="icon">
          <i className="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div className="toggle-switch">
          <label className="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="switch-style" onClick={this.handleClick} />
          <div className="slider round" id="lightDarkToggle"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
          <i className="fa fa-moon-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LightDarkToggle;```
````

Comment: For feedback/refactoring/etc. you want the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use React Context. Context is very easy to use and you don't have to write long code. Please check these official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html , they have also done the same thing but in a React way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I've recently worked on myself. I can provide some guidance, perhaps.

We'll make use of the fact that you can use data-attributes on `html`.

We can also use CSS variables to make this very easy. You can then define a variable in the data-theme attribute selector on HTML and it will be applied to all children of HTML using that attribute.

You're already using localStorage for saving the currently selected theme, which is good. I don't think there's any improvement to be made there.

Here's a quick example I threw together of the above mentioned ideas put together: https://jsfiddle.net/gc9m8pea/2/

And here's snippet form, though it won't actually function because localStorage isn't permitted here.

```js
function getTheme() {
    // Default to Light if key not present.
 return window.localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light';
}

function getOppositeTheme() {
 const theme = getTheme();
  if (theme === 'light')
   return 'dark';
  else
   return 'light';
}

window.onload = () => {
 const button = document.querySelector('#themeToggle');
  const html = document.querySelector('html');
  
  if (html)
   html.setAttribute('data-theme', getTheme());
    
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   const newTheme = getOppositeTheme();
   html.setAttribute('data-theme', newTheme);
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
  });
};
```

```css
html[data-theme="dark"] {
  --bg-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  --text-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

html[data-theme="light"] {
  --bg-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --text-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="themeToggle">
      Toggle Theme
    </button>
    <hr>
    Hello world
  </body>
</html>
```

This should be fairly easy to use inside React, as the concepts themselves are not React-specific.

Hope this helps!