# Priority CSS sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am coding a light and dark mode in ruby on rails and want to know how to a) switch between two style sheets but more so b) how to set one as a default. I know that using !important will utilize portions of one over the other but I am confused for the entirety.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapStyleSheet(pagesheet, headsheet){
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href',pagesheet);
        document.getElementById('headstyle').setAttribute('href',headsheet);
    }
</script>

<button type="button" ><!--onClick="swapStyleSheet('css/show/application_dark.css','css/show/application.css')">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="application_dark.css">
  Dark Theme
</button>

<button type="button" ><!--onClick="swapStyleSheet('css/show/application.css','css/show/application_dark.css')">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css">
  Light Theme
</button>
```

Comment: You can try using HTML data attributes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200675/1852119 where I've got an example of this

Answer (score 1):

I think a good approach is to have two style sheets for the page. One for dark mode and one for light mode.

Then, have some button with an event listener that changes the class of the parent element on the page.

The initial styles will just be whatever class you have assigned in the template.

This is how I'm achieving this exact same feature with ROR on my personal website.

When you load the page both css files exist, but the javascript is just switching out the selector on the parent element.

**This is the scss file for my page in light mode**

```
#taylor-light {
  background: $taylor-gray;
  .bigger, .smaller {
    fill: $taylor-red;
    stroke: $taylor-red;
  }

  .taylor-dark-mode-index {
    background-color: $taylor-blue;
    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        .moon {
          fill: $taylor-red;
        }
    }
    .sun {
      display: none;
    }
  
    .moon {
      fill: $taylor-gray;
    }
}

  .red-text {
    color: $taylor-red;
  }

  .blue-text {
    color: $taylor-blue;
  }

  .form-label {
    display: none;
  }
...
```

**This is the scss file for my page in dark-mode**

```
#taylor {
  background: $taylor-black;
  .bigger, .smaller {
    fill: $taylor-red;
    stroke: $taylor-red;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar{
    background-color: $taylor-black;
  }

  .taylor-dark-mode-index {
    background-color: $taylor-gray;
    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        .sun {
          fill: $taylor-red;
        }
    }
    .sun {
      fill: $taylor-blue;
    }
  
    .moon {
      display: none;
    }
}
...
```

**my javascript class looks like this. The css already exists so all I have to do is change the id of the parent element when the dark mode button is clicked**

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
    if(!event.target.matches('.taylor-dark-mode-index')) return
      console.log('clacky clack')
    if(event.target.dataset.toggle == 'dark'){
      event.target.dataset.toggle = 'light'
       document.querySelector('#taylor').id = 'taylor-light'
    } else if(event.target.dataset.toggle == 'light') {
        event.target.dataset.toggle = 'dark'
        document.querySelector('#taylor-light').id = 'taylor'
    }


}, false);
```

**Then, my html has a top level element which is used to swap out styles**

```
#taylor.template
  .taylor-dark-mode-index[data-toggle="dark"]
    == load_svg(name: 'moon', klass: 'moon dark-mode-toggle')
    == load_svg(name: 'sun', klass: 'sun dark-mode-toggle')
  main
    header
      h1.noselect
        strong
          | Taylor Coon 
        br
        span.red-text
          | Front-end 
        | Software Engineer
      h2.noselect
        span.red-text
          | Ruby
        | , Typescript
...
```

**Here is the actual webpage so you can see the results**

http://www.tacoon.me/taylor-coon